# Android EditText field being set to current time and not time inputed by user

Tags: java, android, calendar, android-edittext

I have a class that wraps a DatePicker and TimePicker dialoagues into a single view pager view so that the user can choose both a date and time. This methods returns a calendar object.

```
public class DialogUtils {
    public static Calendar showDateAndTimeDialog(final Context context) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_date_time,null, false);
        final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
        final TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                return viewPager.getChildAt(position);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return "Date";
                    case 1:
                        return "Time";
                }
                return super.getPageTitle(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return viewPager.getChildCount();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == object;
            }
        });
        final TabLayout layoutTab = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_tab);
        layoutTab.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        final AlertDialog dateAndTimeDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create();
        dateAndTimeDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {

                /*
                    We override the default BUTTON_POSITIVE OnClickListener to prevent the dialog
                    from dismissing when the user presses OK
                 */

                dateAndTimeDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                                    return;
                                }

                                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
                                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
                                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());

                                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

                                // We must dismiss the dialog as we have overriden the default behavior
                                dialog.dismiss();
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
        dateAndTimeDialog.show();
        return calendar;
    }
}
```

This is called in my Activity class in two places. The first

```
public Calendar launchDateAndTimePicker(View view) {
       return DialogUtils.showDateAndTimeDialog(this);
    }
```

and also in the `onCreate` method of my Activity inside a click listener like so

```
mEditDueDate = ((EditText) findViewById(R.id.task_due_date));
        mEditDueDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar cal;
                cal = launchDateAndTimePicker(v);
                // Bitmask used to determine timestamp format
                int displayMask = DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR;

                // Resultant timestamp
                String timestamp = DateUtils.formatDateTime(getApplicationContext(), cal.getTimeInMillis(), displayMask);
                mEditDueDate.setText(timestamp);
            }
        });
    }
```

Even after I select a new date and time, my EditText field displays the current date and time. I feel like how i am initialising a calendar object is clobbering the values set by the Picker widgets. How should i extract the calendar values from the calendar object returned by `showDateAndTimeDialog`?

**Edit for Solution**

I updated the DialogUtils class to take an Activity in its constructor and update the EditText field directly.

```
public Activity editActivity;
    public static EditText mEditDueDate;

    public DialogUtils(Activity editActivity) {
        this.editActivity = editActivity;
    }
```

and then find the EditText field

```
 mEditDueDate = (EditText) editActivity.findViewById(R.id.task_due_date);
```

and later update the EditText field.

```
// Bitmask used to determine timestamp format
                                int displayMask = DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_TIME | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_DATE | DateUtils.FORMAT_SHOW_YEAR;
                                String timestamp = DateUtils.formatDateTime(editActivity.getApplicationContext(), calendar.getTimeInMillis(), displayMask);
                                mEditDueDate.setText(timestamp);

                                // We must dismiss the dialog as we have overriden the default behavior
                                dialog.dismiss();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the time the timestamp is extracted and set to the `EditText`, the user has not yet entered a date.

You should move

```
// Resultant timestamp
String timestamp = DateUtils.formatDateTime(getApplicationContext(), cal.getTimeInMillis(), displayMask);
mEditDueDate.setText(timestamp);
```

to a `DialogInterface.OnClickListener.onClick` maybe implemented within the surrounding class.

And when you build your dialog add the listener to the positive button of the dialog:

```
final AlertDialog dateAndTimeDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
            .setView(view)
            .setPositiveButton("OK", this)
            .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
            .create();
```

Of course you will have make the result `Calendar` object available in the OnClickListener.

Comment: I've updated my activity to implement `DialogInterface.OnDismissListener` and i've added an `onDismiss()` method with `@Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogue) {
        String timestamp = DateUtils.formatDateTime(this, cal.getTimeInMillis(), displayMask);
        mEditDueDate.setText(timestamp);
    }` but now instead of the edittext being updated to the current date and time, it's not updated at all? Where should I implement the `OnDismissListenter`?

Comment: yet another edit: `OnDismissListener` was rather redundant. You can give your dialog an `OnClickListener` for the positive button. This way, cancel won't change the `EditText`.

Comment: I updated DialogUtils to take my EditActivity class in its constructor. Is this an instance where I should be using Dependency Injection? Also, my solution updates the edittext field from the Dialogue utils class, this is suboptimal as the two are now tightly coupled, yes?

Comment: Well, instead requiring an `Activity` in the constructor, you could make it a bit more generic by using the `DialogInterface` callback listerners: `public DialogUtils(OnClickListener positiveButtonListener, ...) { ... }` with as many listeners as you need and some *secondary constructors* for convenience. The listeners should be implemented within the Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You are returning your calendar before setting selected data on it.

Try it asynchronous like this.

```
public class DialogUtils {
    public static void showDateAndTimeDialog(final Context context, final DateCallback dateCallback) {

        View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.dialog_date_time,null, false);
        final DatePicker datePicker = (DatePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.date_picker);
        final TimePicker timePicker = (TimePicker) view.findViewById(R.id.time_picker);
        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.view_pager);
        final Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        viewPager.setAdapter(new PagerAdapter() {

            @Override
            public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
                return viewPager.getChildAt(position);
            }

            @Override
            public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
                switch (position) {
                    case 0:
                        return "Date";
                    case 1:
                        return "Time";
                }
                return super.getPageTitle(position);
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return viewPager.getChildCount();
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
                return view == object;
            }
        });
        final TabLayout layoutTab = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_tab);
        layoutTab.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);

        final AlertDialog dateAndTimeDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(context)
                .setView(view)
                .setPositiveButton("OK", null)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", null)
                .create();
        dateAndTimeDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {
            @Override
            public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {

                /*
                    We override the default BUTTON_POSITIVE OnClickListener to prevent the dialog
                    from dismissing when the user presses OK
                 */

                dateAndTimeDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setOnClickListener(
                        new View.OnClickListener() {

                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                if (viewPager.getCurrentItem() == 0) {
                                    viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                                    return;
                                }

                                calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, datePicker.getMonth());
                                calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, datePicker.getDayOfMonth());
                                calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, datePicker.getYear());

                                calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, timePicker.getCurrentHour());
                                calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, timePicker.getCurrentMinute());

                                // We must dismiss the dialog as we have overriden the default behavior
                                dialog.dismiss();

                                dateCallback.onDateSelected(calendar);
                            }
                        });
            }
        });
        dateAndTimeDialog.show();
    }

    private interface DateCallback {
        void onDateSelected(Calendar calendar);
    }
}
```